# Create a User with Model Bakery

Tags: django-models, pytest, django-testing, model-mommy

I would like to create a Person instance with Model Bakery.  My Person model looks like this:

```
User = get_user_model()

class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="friend", on_delete=CASCADE)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

My baker_recipes.py looks like this:

```
from model_bakery.recipe import Recipe

User = get_user_model()
test_user = User(username="test_user")

person = Recipe(Person, user = test_user)
```

My tests.py looks like this:

```
import pytest
from model_bakery import baker

@pytest.mark.django_db()
class TestPerson:
    def setup(self):
        self.person = baker.make_recipe("company.tests.person")

    def test_country_access(self):
        assert True
```

But when I run pytest with this set up I get the following error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: insert or update on table "company_person" violates foreign key constraint "company_person_user_id_4f1cc5d0_fk_auth_user_id"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(411) is not present in table "auth_user".
```

Comment: What is `Recipe(Person, user = test_user)` (especially `Person` and the `Recipe`) doing here?

Comment: I've edited my question to provide more context.  Recipe is a class from Model Bakery that allows you to specify the inputs to a particular instance you want to create.  When you call baker.make_recipe, it then makes the recipe (i.e. creates and populates a temporary database table with this data)

Comment: Can you show `Recipe`

Answer (score 1):

```py
    import pytest
    from model_bakery import baker
    
    @pytest.mark.django_db()
    class TestPerson:
        def setup(self):
            # replace this
            self.person = baker.make_recipe("company.tests.person")
            # with this
            self.person = baker.make(Person, ...optional_field_params)
    
        def test_country_access(self):
            assert a_condition_is_true
            # assert True is not logical here so comented out
```

N.B with `baker.make` the created instance is persisted to the test db on setup with `baker.prepare`  on the other hand  it is not persisted.